# Running Unit Test w/ App Directory In Django 1.6+

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I have my Django project structured so all the apps are in the apps directory.

```
/manage.py
/apps/events/tests.py
/apps/contacts/tests.py
```

This worked until Django 1.6, but now when I try to run

```
./manage.py test events
```

I get the following error:

```
  File "/Users/josephmisiti/mathandpencil/projects/xxxx/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 63, in build_suite
    tests = self.test_loader.loadTestsFromName(label)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 91, in loadTestsFromName
    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))
ImportError: No module named events
```

I my settings.py, I have the following under INSTALLED_APPS

```
'apps.contacts',
'apps.events',
```

Anyone know how to fix this one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In 1.6 the command is:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#running-tests)

`$ ./manage.py test events`

The docs assume your folder structure has every app in the root of the project folder.

But if you have structured your folders differently you will need to match that in the command.

So from your project root, if you have a folder named `apps` and in there an app named `events` your command will look like:

`$ ./manage.py test apps.events`

Comment: thanks! - i was hoping there was a way to tell django that the apps live in the app folder but i guess there is not.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But whenever I try the answer you said I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'apps' has no attribute '__file__'`